# Copy constructor on C# struct, that works like a C++ copy constructor

Tags: c#, c++

Is it possible to have a copy constructor on a C# struct, that works like a C++ copy constructor? Because mine isn't working.

Specifically, it's not being called automatically during an assignment, as would happen with a C++ copy constructor.

```cs
struct TestStruct
{
    public TestStruct(TestStruct other)
    {
        // this function is never called
    }
}

public void Afunction()
{
    TestStruct A = new TestStruct();
    TestStruct B = new TestStruct();

    A = B; // in c++ copy constructor would be called here
}
```

Comment: The copy constructor isn't called, because you are not calling it... Constructors don't get called automatically. `TestStruct B = new TestStruct(A);` will call it.

Comment: ok so I'm coming from a c++, Are you saying that c# has no concept of a copy constructor? Because what you are showing there is just a constructor, that happens to take one parameter of the struct's type.

Can you overload the assignment operator?

Comment: (I don't know anything about C++) So you are saying that in C++, the assignment operator on structs will call a special "copy constructor"? No, that doesn't exist in C#. "Copy constructors" are just regular constructors as far as the language is concerned. Programmers still like to call them that sometimes because they "copy" values. Also, `=` is not one of the overloadable operators.

Comment: Sweeper already told you how to do it. What's wrrong with it?

Comment: I don't think the question is all that bad, maybe the lack of details and explanation might be causing the (only 2) down votes, here have a charity vote.

Comment: "I am trying to transparently replace a native value type (int) with a struct or class, and having a hell of a time." Now you have explained a bit about what your actual problem is, I think we are getting closer to the problem X of this XY problem, but still not quite. Can you explain why you want to replace `int` with your own type? What problem are you trying to solve with this? C# is not designed for you to do that.

Comment: Microsoft tells us there is no implicit copy constructor, only workarounds... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-write-a-copy-constructor

Comment: Thanks @Sweeper, I think that answers my question.

I was worried my actual problem would be far too specific to be useful to others. 

Basically, I was using a ulong for bitmasks. Imagine an editor where you have layers, you can have multiple layers visible at once, and entities can belong to multiple layers.

Problem was, we decided we wanted more than 64 layers. So I wanted to replace the ulong with my own struct that could have as many bits as you wanted by way of an internal array.

Comment: we do a lot of &= and |= operations on the masks, and I wanted to avoid creating a new array each time for each operation (which would need to be done, as the array could have become shared by other 'instances' of the struct, if it had been copied: (A = B; B&=C, I didn't want the op on B to change A)

So I was planning on adding a ref count to the array, so I'd only copy it for a modify operation if it was actually possibly being shared.

Comment: To everyone downvoting the question: Someone is asking for language feature comparison across two widely used languages. Stop being pedantic about it.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, Thanks, But to be fair my original question didn't mention c++. someone who knew c# but not c++ would not know what my concept of a 'copy constructor' is.

Comment: IMHO, you get downvotes because you already have the solution in your code, you just didn't use it. Basically it's like you wrote a method but never call it. And for that, it doesn't matter whether you're new to a language or not

Comment: @ThomasWeller IMHO you don't know what a c++ copy constructor is.

Comment: @ThomasWeller C# has no equivalent concept. Indeed, CLR has no such concept.

Comment: It does not really affect the question, but I believe that in your sample code, C++ does not call the copy constructor. It calls the assignment operator,see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_operator_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: @user74696c oh really? even if only the copy constructor is defined?

Comment: @matt Yes, the assignment operator is always generated implicitly. It is a bit hypothetical because your code is C# and not C++ anyways. But in C++, the copy ctor is not called in "A=B" because TestStruct A was already constructed before in "TestStruct A = new TestStruct()". If you put the declaration and assignment in one line "TestStruct A = B", then the copy ctor is called.

Comment: Even in C++ `A = B` doesn't call the copy constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since others have already answered the question about how to call the "copy constructor" (which would be to pass the other instance to the constructor: `TestStruct B = new TestStruct(A);)`, I'll try to answer the other questions.

> *"Can you have a copy constructor for a C# struct, that works like a C++ copy constructor?"*

No. In C++ a copy constructor is automatically called during an assignment of a type to another instance of that type. In C#, a shallow copy of the object is made, meaning that the value of value-type members is copied, and the reference of reference-type members is copied.

> *From the comments: "Can you overload the assignment operator?"*

No. The assignment operator is not something that can be redefined. The default behavior for the language is what happens every time. Of course you can write your own method that returns a new instance of a type based on the property values of another instance, but that method must be called explicitly, and cannot be defined such that it's called during an assignement.

> *Also from the comments: "I am trying to transparently replace a native value type (int) with a struct or class"*

Well now here it sounds like you might have something to work with. Although I'm really not sure what you mean by "replace a native value type", c# *does* allow you to write your own [user-defined conversion operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators) which allow implicit (and explicit) conversions between two types. This effectively overrides the assignment operator *when you're assigning from a different type.*

Granted, this is not what your example is doing, but based on your comment it may be useful.

For example, if you wanted to create in instance of your struct from an `int`, you can do:

```
struct MyIntReplacement
{
    public int MyValue { get; set; }

    public static implicit operator MyIntReplacement(int value)
    {
        return new MyIntReplacement { MyValue = value };
    }
}
```

And now you can do something like:

```
int someValue = 5;
MyIntReplacement foo = someValue;
```

Comment: Thanks, This is likely the best answer, and it certainly answers the question.

I did find that implicit operator thingy too, which is cool. Of course it doesn't let you have MyIntReplacement as the parameter, which would effectively make it a copy constructor.  I get the feeling they just didn't want the added complexity of value type copy constructors in the language.  explicit assignment is one thing, but they'd also have to consider it when copying sub struct objects, or struct arrays (they wouldn't be able to just do big memcpys as they have the option of doing now).

Answer (score 8):

It is because you are not calling your parameterized-constructor. Take a look at the code below:

```
struct TestStruct
{
    public string WhoIsCalled;
    public TestStruct(TestStruct other)
    {
        // this function is never called
        WhoIsCalled = "Constructor with argument";
    }

}

public string Afunction()
{

    TestStruct A = new TestStruct();
    return A.WhoIsCalled;

}
public string Bfunction()
{

    TestStruct B = new TestStruct(new TestStruct());
    return B.WhoIsCalled;

}
```

When you run **Afunction**, it returns null. It means that your code is using the default-parameterless-constructor. But in **Bfunction**, your code is providing the parameter, so your constructor is called hence the `WhoIsCalled` string gets value.

Comment: It might be worth talking about struct assignments, and how they act as copy constructors, with the caution that if the struct contains a reference type, only the reference is copied.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why C# does not have copy constructors while C++ does has to do with the semantics either language follows when calling functions/methods.

C++, inheriting its C background, prefers value (or copy) semantics when passing arguments to a function.

C#, running on top of a garbage collected environment - among other reasons - passes its parameters as references.

A function (or method in C#) which looks identical syntax wise

```
void f(string s) { /* does something with s here */ }
```

has very different semantics for how it is invoked. C++ would make a copy of whatever object was being passed in `f(abc)` which C# would simply pass the reference it had in `abc` to `f()` and make `s` point to the same object. Think of `f()` being written in C++ as

```
void f(string& s) { /* does something with s here */ }
```

A similar reasoning applies to `a = b;` meaning copy assignment in C++ while copying reference in C#. Also why you cannot overload `=` in C#.

**P.S.: Nitpickers will not be entertained.**

P.P.S. : Value types actually have value semantics, but still you cannot overload `operator =()` for them.

Comment: "*P.S.: Nitpickers will not be entertained.*" - That sounds like a challenge

Comment: @MichaelRandall hahaha, I am glossing over a lot here, probably full of incorrect terminology and all that. But it is far better to get the idea across seeing how OP doesn't know C# and someone who knows both would be able to provide concept mapping from C++ to C# and back.

Comment: Although technically the `string` class is a reference type, it is immutable. So passing a reference to a string is different than passing a reference to most classes - changing the value that one reference points to creates a new object and changes the reference assignment to refer to that new location, like a value type. Probably a true reference type should be used as an example when talking about struct assignments as copy constructors.

Comment: @RufusL As noted above, my overriding concern when writing that answer was to convey the concept equivalence to the OP rather than nuance about the intricacies of C#, CLR and all that goes with the whole dotnet/runtime. Feel free to suggest a reference type which has the exact same name in C++ too, is widely used, and is not immutable.

Comment: @TanveerBadar How about `MyCustomClass`? :) I think the part that got me was: *"C# ... passes its parameters as references."*. This isn't the case, though. Value types are passed by value, reference types are passed by reference. In the OP's example of the "copy constructor", for example, `TestStruct other` is passed by value, not reference, in c#.